# Apache Drill 0.9 & SQuirreL SQL Client - can't list JDBC dirvers

Tags: java, jdbc, apache-drill, squirrel-sql

I am trying to connect to `Apache Drill 0.9` using `Squirrel SQL` client 3.6 following the instructions [here](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/DRILL/Using+JDBC+to+Access+Apache+Drill+from+SQuirreL).

After adding the `Drill` JDBC driver jar I click the `List Drivers` button and nothing happens... looking at the `Squirrel` log I see errors like:

> 2015-05-14 10:07:49,495 [Thread-2] INFO  net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.db.DriverInternalFrame  - Failed to load org.apache.drill.jdbc.AvaticaDrillSqlAccessor in C:\Dev\Apache\Drill\apache-drill-0.9.0\jars\drill-jdbc-0.9.0.jar to check if it is assignable to java.sql.Driver. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/hydromatic/avatica/Cursor$Accessor
>
> 2015-05-14 10:07:49,501 [Thread-2] INFO  net.sourceforge.squirrel_sql.client.gui.db.DriverInternalFrame  - Failed to load org.apache.drill.jdbc.DrillConnectionConfig in C:\Dev\Apache\Drill\apache-drill-0.9.0\jars\drill-jdbc-0.9.0.jar to check if it is assignable to java.sql.Driver. Reason: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: net/hydromatic/avatica/ConnectionConfigImpl

What could be the issue? BTW I am running on JVM 8.

Comment: FYI: [`squirrel`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squirrel) is for the scripting language, [`squirrel-sql`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/squirrel-sql) is for the SQL client.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like the solution was to add the full path of the Apache Drill jars\classb directory to the Extra class Path in addition to the JDBC driver Jar